# Multiply all columns of a csv table with a constant extracted from another table

Tags: command-line

I have 20 files where the filenames are like: ERR260136.genefamilies.csv, ERR276187.genefamilies.csv, etc. Each file has to be multiplied by one constant. The corresponding constant has to be taken from a .csv file:`read_count.csv`. `The read_count.csv` file is like:

```
SampleID Read_counts
ERR260136 25636740
ERR260140 19166076
ERR260145 28011856
ERR260147 27916650
ERR260148 21871928
ERR260150 30130062
ERR260152 17949808
```

So, ERR260136.genefamilies.csv has to be multiplied by 25636740, ERR260140.genefamilies.csv has to be multiplied by 19166076 and so on...

The 20 files to be multiplied are in this format:

```
# Gene Family   ERR260136_Abundance-RPKs
UNMAPPED    0.445035
UniRef90_A0A015P9C8 0.00080211
UniRef90_A0A015P9C8|g__Bacteroides.s__Bacteroides_fragilis  0.00080211
UniRef90_A5ZYU5 0.000787149
UniRef90_A5ZYU5|g__Blautia.s__Blautia_obeum 0.000787149
UniRef90_A0A0E1X896 0.000573095
UniRef90_A0A0E1X896|g__Blautia.s__Blautia_obeum 0.000573095
```

How can I do this? Can anyone please help?

Comment: You refer to these files as "csv" however what you show appears to be whitespace separated data

Comment: I edited the table while posting the question. Now, I have posted the table in its original form. Thanks steeldriver for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
while read -r sampleID read_count; do 
  # skip header line
  [ "$sampleID" = "SampleID" ] && continue

  awk -v read_count="${read_count}" 'FNR>1 {$2 *= read_count} 1' "${sampleID}.genefamilies.csv"

done < read_count.csv
```

Obviously this is very basic - you may wish to add some error handling for files not found, values non-numeric etc.

Comment: Thanks you so much steeldriver for your help. It is running but not just converting the file outputs for those 20 files after the operation.

Comment: @DEEPCHANDA if you want the files to be modified in-place, then GNU awk (aka `gawk`) now has a `-i inplace` option for that. Otherwise you will need to redirect the output to a file and then rename it.